# Simple online store

Tags: php, wordpress, open-source, e-commerce

I don't want to use wordpress (with wp-ecommerce plugin) or other full-featured store scripts because my requirement is quite simple and limited:

2 product types: bags, tees
3 categories: classic, modern, special
3 sort options: by color, by category, by price
Cart with PayPal as payment processor.

Is there any lightweight (and open-source) script that does all this while allowing me to customize the look and feel easily?

Many thanks!

Comment: what is programming related in thin question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the one you are looking for
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-simple-paypal-shopping-cart/

Very simple to use ;)
you can also see the demo. But I fear it has no sorting option :(

Answer (score 2):

**If you don't mind using PayPal's shopping cart:**

- [**Creating an Add to Cart button**](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/xcl/web-accept-to-sc-button-outside)

Otherwise:

- [osCommerce](http://www.oscommerce.com/) (PHP) - [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OsCommerce)
- [osCommerce Templates](http://www.freetemplatesonline.com/free-oscommerce-templates/)
- [Zen Cart](http://www.zen-cart.com/) (PHP) - [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_Cart)
- [Zen Cart templates](http://www.zenflavor.com/)
- [dashCommerce](http://dashcommerce.org/default.aspx) (ASP.NET)

Other ideas (not all open source though):

- [Comparison of shopping cart software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_shopping_cart_software)
- [10 kick ass Open source E-commerce platforms reviewed](http://blog.webdistortion.com/2008/05/03/9-kick-ass-open-source-e-commerce-platforms-reviewed/)